# HTML,CSS : a href image to the left , in <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to align an image (which is also a link) to the left of my list.
I have tried using:

- `align="left"` the image goes to the middle of the screen.
- `display:inline`,`display:inline-block`,`display:block`  and nothing changes to the images position.

Anyone knows how to solve this ?
I posted everything on *fiddle*:
http://jsfiddle.net/vazjLqwv/

*Note: this is what i am trying to do:* http://i.gyazo.com/bbee47d76535f87a7dba09cee2dd7083.png

Comment: the image should not be a part of the list if it's supposed to appear outside of it.

Comment: i want the image to be inside of the list , left of the text

Comment: To left? it is align to left:D Align to right: http://jsfiddle.net/vazjLqwv/2/

Comment: I need the image to be on the left of the text guys , isnt it clear ? :S let me upload an image so that you guys understand http://i.gyazo.com/bbee47d76535f87a7dba09cee2dd7083.png

Comment: my original comment still stands.

Comment: @tenub i explained that the image is still a part of the list, it is just another item on the `<li></li>` brackets , the only difference is that its position is different

Comment: modify your html so that it makes more semantic sense rather than setting css properties as a workaround. that was what i was implying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do with float:left in the a that holds the image, or you could use 'display:inline-block', but in the second case you will need a wrapper to hold the others 'a's, see the changes i made at http://jsfiddle.net/vazjLqwv/1/

each li:

```
<li>
    <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd"><img src="http://andreiverner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/how-to-create-psychedelic-landscape-vector-cd-cover-with-adobe-illustrator-part-ii.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px"></a>
    <p>
       <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Album: asd asdasd ads asdas asal</a>
       <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Song: asdasdsadasd asd</a>
       <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Artist: asdasd d  dsd dsadasd asd</a>
    </p>
</li>
```

and the css:

```
#itemContainer li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#itemContainer li > p {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#itemContainer li > p > a {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: um, the only problem with this code , is that when the text in `album: ` is really long , the image goes in the top of the text, not on the left, do you know how to fix this ? thanks..

Answer (score 1):

its done and updated in **[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vazjLqwv/19/)** cheers!

```
<ul id="itemContainer">   
          <li>
              <a class="one" href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Album: asd asdasd ads asdas asal</a>
              <a class="one" href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Song: asdasdsadasd asd</a>
              <a class="one" href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Artist: asdasd d  dsd dsadasd asd</a>
              <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd"><img src="http://andreiverner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/how-to-create-psychedelic-landscape-vector-cd-cover-with-adobe-illustrator-part-ii.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px"></a>
              </li>
              <li>juicy-r</li>
              <li>its all about the</li>      
              <li>asdsadsad</li>
              <li>asd</li>
              <li>dsa</li>    
              <li>dsa</li>
              <li>asdsadsad</li>
              <li>asd</li>
              <li>dsa</li>  
              <li>asdsadsad</li>
              <li>asd</li>
              <li>dsa</li>  
          </ul>
```

CSS

```
a img{
    float:left;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 0;
    display:block;  
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.one{
   margin-left:110px;
top:-10px;
position:relative;    
}
div#content { 
width: 990px;  
display: inline-block;
}

a { 
color: #222;
text-decoration: none; 
}

a:visited { 
color: #222; 
}

a:focus { 
outline: thin dotted; 
}

a:hover, a:active { 
outline: 0;   
}

ul#itemContainer { 
list-style: none; 
padding:0; 
margin: 20px 0; 
    padding-top:40px;
  width: 990px; 
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
}

ul#itemContainer li { 
display: block; 
margin: 5px; 
zoom: 1;
  font: 200 15px/1.5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*
#itemContainer  li:last-child{
  border: none;
}
*/ 

#itemContainer li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;

  -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
}

#itemContainer li:hover {

}

#itemContainer li a:hover {

    color: silver;
}

.holder {
margin: 15px 0;
}

.holder a {
font-size: 12px;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0 5px;
color: #333;
}

.holder a:hover {
background-color: #222;
color: #fff;
}

.holder a.jp-previous { 
margin-right: 15px; 
}

.holder a.jp-next { 
margin-left: 15px; 
}

.holder a.jp-current, a.jp-current:hover {
color: #FF4242;
font-weight: bold;
}

.holder a.jp-disabled, a.jp-disabled:hover {
color: #bbb;
}

.holder a.jp-current, a.jp-current:hover, .holder a.jp-disabled, a.jp-disabled:hover {
cursor: default;
background: none;
}

.holder span { 
margin: 0 5px; 
}

form { 
float: right; 
margin-right: 10px; 
}

form label { 
margin-right: 5px; 
}
```

Comment: the icon should be on the left of the first `<li></li>` brackets text, like in http://jsfiddle.net/vazjLqwv/1/

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED THE CODE CHECK AND LET ME KNOW

Comment: this looks exactly what i want but it is missing the `transition` effect i had , i am trying to add it and i cant, where should i add it ? do you know ?

Comment: -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;

Answer (score 1):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vazjLqwv/14/) which uses the following CSS

```
 a img{
    float:left;
    display:block;   
}
```

I have just written an `<a>` tag with `<img>` before another `<a>` tag in `<li>`

```
<li>
           <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd"><img src="http://andreiverner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/how-to-create-psychedelic-landscape-vector-cd-cover-with-adobe-illustrator-part-ii.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px"></a>
           <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Album: asd asdasd ads asdas asal</a>
           <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Song: asdasdsadasd asd</a>
           <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Artist: asdasd d  dsd dsadasd asd</a>
</li>
```

Comment: thank you , not exactly what i am looking for , still useful though

Answer (score 1):

To only change the LIST:

```
  <ul id="itemContainer">     
      <li><div style="float:left;"><a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Album: asd asdasd ads asdas asal</a>
          <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Song: asdasdsadasd asd</a>
          <a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd">Artist: asdasd d  dsd dsadasd asd</a>
          </div><a href="?album=asdasd?song=asdasd"><img src="http://andreiverner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/how-to-create-psychedelic-landscape-vector-cd-cover-with-adobe-illustrator-part-ii.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px"/></a>
          </li>
      </ul>
```

Make a DIV around the links and set the float to left. And the IMG is not in the DIV.

Greetings